# Multisim Multimeter showing blank reading (--------)

Tags: dc, multimeter, basic, multisim

I am trying to build a simple circuit to back up some hand calculations that I am completing for a project. However I am unable to get a reading on the Multisim multimeter. I have changed the simulation type to interactive as that is what I have found in another thread.

[image]

Comment: This is not a support forum for using commercial software - You should be asking this on the Multisim support forum because that is what it is for.

Comment: Ahh sorry could you point me in the right direction i'm new to this

Comment: @Justme we have answered a lot of questions on multiple tools here. There are 221 questions using the multisim tag. So I'd say this is fine here as well.

Comment: Manged to sort it now thanks Guys

Comment: @Jacob if you have a solution, please take the time and answer your own question (and accept that answer). It might help some future person - or even a future you if you stumble upon it again. This might seem strange at first, but it is completely fine - even encouraged.

Comment: @Arsenal Thanks have done that now

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue by restarting Multisim and switching between interactive mode and DC Op and it seemed to solve the problem :)

Comment: No need to add "Solved" to the title.  You can click accept on your answer, then the system will know (and correctly show) that your question has a solution.  It might make you wait a day before you can accept it, though.